# how to make picasso display default image when there is an invalid path

Tags: android, picasso

I am having one issue on display a default image name here R.drawable.avatar_placeholder.  When the link from webservice is non empty, but error 404. means there isn't any image on that link path. Which if i run this function below, the string "path not empty" is shown, but it failed to display the image.  Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks.

```
private void loadProfileDetails() {
        Logger.d(UI_LoginFragmentWithPin.class, "loadProfileDetails profile image: " + PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE));
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE))){
            Utils.println("path not empty");
            LPicasso.getInstance(getActivity())
                    .load(PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE))
                    .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imgProfile);
        }else {
            Utils.println("path empty");
            LPicasso.getInstance(getActivity())
                    .load(R.drawable.avatar_placeholder)
                    .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imgProfile);

        }
        tvEmail.setText(PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_EMAIL));
        tvName.setText(PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_USER_NAME) + " " + PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_USER_SURNAME));
    }
```

Comment: Just add `.error(R.drawable.placeholder)'

Comment: @Rajesh Kushvaha  Sweet....!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

Set error image as your place holder image

```
    if(!PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE).equals("")) 
    {
        Picasso.with(context).load(PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE)).resize(200,200).centerCrop().error(R.drawable.avatar_placeholder).into(imgProfile);
    }
    else
    {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.avatar_placeholder).error(R.drawable.avatar_placeholder).resize(200,200).centerCrop().into(imgProfile);
    }
```

gradle:

```
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Are the conditions really necessary? If the image is not present the .error(..) method will itself take care of that.

Comment: and btw if(!PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE).equals(""))  will crash if the value in your SharePreference is null.  is better to do the other way.  if("".equals(!PrefUtils.readString(Constant.PREF_PROFILE_IMAGE)))

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
    Picasso.with(this)
     .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")        
     .placeholder(DRAWABLE RESOURCE)       
     .error(DRAWABLE RESOURCE)      // Image to load when something goes wrong 
     .resize(width, height)                            
     .rotate(degree)                                 
     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: what is the difference between  your answer and already given by user2025187 answer..??

Comment: His answer posted before mine. You can't two answer within 3 minutes

Answer (score -2):

Picasso are not manging android memorey & slow ,
so i am higley recommend you to not to use it 
and instade of it just use Glide libeary .

(You can download image and make her circle with glide , download image a Bitmap and much more )

add to Gradle:

> repositories {   mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it
>   pulls from Maven Central }
>
> dependencies {   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
>   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0' }

and just:

for load a pic:

```
Glide.with(this).load("URL").into(imageView);
```

and you can add a lot more functionality by glide ,
for example if you want a placeholder until the photo will load 
you are just adding .placeholder():
  :

> Glide.with(this).load("URL").placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView);

and if you want a to display photo incase of the photo you are trying to load is broken or have any problem , just add   .error()

:

> Glide.with(this).load("URL").error(R.drawable.error).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since my current project is using Picasso, I will try your suggestion when I have the spare time. As you know, we are rushing to get the project done. :P